# How do I determine the rank and signature of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-rank

The quadratic form is given: $f=x_1x_2-x_2x_3$ I have to determine a rank and signature of it. What is the way to do it? ( I know that usually I have to transform a matrix into upper triangular form to determine the rank, but in this case on diagonal it is all zeros and there is no way I can transform it to be a upper diagonal matrix)

$$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

The only thing I could think of was to add to the first column the third one and the first row to the third row, then the first column will be all zeros and I willl change to columns to look it as follows:

$$\left[\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$
I now that by switching rows or columns you change determinan, but is it important in this case? Any case,  the rank for this form is $r=2$ am I right? ( I just don't  know for sure how to determine it)

Answer (score 2):

Write the quadratic form on its [reduced form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormSignature.html) i.e. with squared terms:

$$x_1x_2-x_2x_3=x_2(x_1-x_3)=\frac14(x_2+x_1-x_3)^2-\frac14(x_2-x_1+x_3)^2.$$
hence the signature is $(1,1)$ and the rank is $r=2$.

Comment: Maybe you know some online source where it's explained how to write the quadratic form on its reduced form?

Comment: It's so simple and bases on two equalities:

- complete the square: $a^2+b^2=(a+b/2)^2-b^2/4$ and

-  $ab=\frac14((a+b)^2-(a-b)^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$