# How to determine the rank of a matrix if on the diagonal it's all zeros?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-rank

Can someone tell, what's the way to determine the rank for a quadratic form? I know one way to determine the signature, that is by finding the eigenvalues. For a quadratic form $f=x_1x_2-x_2x_3$ the signature would be $(1,1)$, because there is one positive and one negative eigenvalue. But how do I determine the rank? I know that you can complete the square and then determine. I am not sure whether I do the completion of the squares the right way: $(x_1+\frac{1}{2}x_2)^2-\frac{1}{4}x_2^2-x_1^2+(x_2-\frac{1}{2}x_3)^2-x_2^2-\frac{1}{4}x_3^2$ I am quite sure that this is no the right way for completing the square, can someone explain how can I do it properly and also how can I determine the rank after completion of the square?

Comment: What’s your definition of the rank of a quadratic form?

Comment: @amd Well you can transform quadratic form into matrix. $A=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: Yes, you can, but that doesn’t tell me what your definition of the rank of a quadratic form is.

Comment: I put a complete algorithmic answer at your earlier https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246597/how-do-i-determine-the-rank-and-signature-of-a-quadratic-form   with links to references